# PHP , class inside class , bug?

Tags: php, oop, class, include

B.php:

```
   class B
   {
   function show() { echo 'works'; }
   }
```

A.php

```
class A
{

 public static function defineB()
 {
  include "b.php";
 }

}


A::defineB();
$b = new B;
var_dump($b);
```

object(B)#1 (0) { } ,

if without A::defineB(); - Fatal error: Class 'B' not found ,
if define class without including another file - Fatal error: Class declarations may not be nested ,

is it bug ?

Comment: It is a bug, but not in PHP. You can't nest class declarations as the error message says.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it allowed to create a php class inside another class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583140/is-it-allowed-to-create-a-php-class-inside-another-class)

Comment: What version of PHP do you use? Given [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608432/php-nested-classes-work-sort-of) this should work, since `include()` includes classes in the global namespace.

Comment: "Given this question this should work, since include() includes classes in the global namespace" if its global , why its isnt defined untill i use  A::defineB(); ?

Comment: @JohnFaker Just in case you never figured it out, `include()` is not going to put the "included" stuff INSIDE of the function. It simply parses the information.  Class declarations and function declarations are not going to be inside of `defineB`, but are instead automatically added to the global scope.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a bug, it is default and correct behaviour.

You should include files before using them. If this gives you too much pain, you could use http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php or http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php in the beginning of your code.

Comment: if its not a bug ,why i dont have a error - Fatal error: Class declarations may not be nested ? why code works ?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can not nesting classes (as in Java) - so you got "Class declarations may not be nested". The key word is **namespace**. Including class `B` from method of class `A` does not affect the name of class `A` that is still... "A" and not "B\A", "B.A" or sth. :)