# php inner classes support

Tags: php

Does PHP versions 5.3 or after support inner classes?
example:

```
class MyClass{
    class PrivateClass1{

    }
    class PrivateClass2{

    }
    class PrivateClass3{

    }

    private $obj1;
    private $obj2;
    private $obj3;

    __construct(){
        $obj1 = new PrivateClass1();
        $obj2 = new PrivateClass2();
        $obj3 = new PrivateClass3();
    }
}
```

Comment: In which version did you try this?

Comment: What is the purpose of an inner class? And what other languages support them? I'm intrigued.

Comment: No php does not support nested classes.  @Lion I dont think he tried. It contains lots of errors. no `$` sign. no `function` keyword for method declaration

Comment: This looks like a Jaca snippet, if I may believe [this bugreport](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51469) inner classes are not yet supported.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it allowed to create a php class inside another class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583140/is-it-allowed-to-create-a-php-class-inside-another-class)

Comment: @MarkBaker C# supports them... VB supports them. ALL.NET support them

Comment: @Cole Johnson: dotnet ain't no PHP not at all.

Comment: @hakre I didn't say it was. I was answering this:  "What is the purpose of an inner class? And what other languages support them?"

Comment: I haven't tried but I would like to!!! Thank you very much for your answers. I need it to do so I asked

Comment: @Mark Baker Java supports inner classes

Comment: @Johntor:) Java supports inner classes but it has whatsoever nothing to do with PHP as obvious.

Comment: @Lion yes but PHP is getting better and better!! When I started there was no OOP support at all!!

Comment: Well it answers the second part of my question, still unsure of their purpose

Comment: At least for me, I use inner classes when I want to use them 'privately' into my class only. So I make them and put them into one file nicely and tidy!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PHP currently (5.4.3) does not support Inner/Friend Classes

And there is also no [RFC in the wiki](https://wiki.php.net/rfc) asking for addition of a feature like this.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to create a class within another class definiton,
but it's not possible to define a class within a class definition.
So this means your construction in invalid.

But, you can always extend a class with another class, check this URL for more:

http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php

Check [Can I instantiate a PHP class inside another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583140/is-it-allowed-to-create-a-php-class-inside-another-class) for even more.

Comment: Sorry I know how to extend a class. I need to create something like this example

Comment: @Johntor Yes i think someone who asks for class nesting knows about extending, I just wanted to give an alternative for people who read this thing in future.